# Testing with jest a register form ( react App)

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

It's my first time doing testing in general and I am trying to test a register page (check if the forms input are correctly working and if will create the user at the end). This is my register page:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";
import { isEmail } from "validator";

import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";

const required = (value) => {
  if (!value) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This field is required!
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const validEmail = (value) => {
  if (!isEmail(value)) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This is not a valid email.
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const vusername = (value) => {
  if (value.length < 3 || value.length > 20) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        The username must be between 3 and 20 characters.
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const vpassword = (value) => {
  if (value.length < 6 || value.length > 40) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        The password must be between 6 and 40 characters.
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const Register = (props) => {
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    const username = e.target.value;
    setUsername(username);
  };

  const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    setEmail(email);
  };

  const onChangePassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    setPassword(password);
  };

  const handleRegister = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setMessage("");
    setSuccessful(false);

    form.current.validateAll();

    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      AuthService.register(username, email, password).then(
        (response) => {
          setMessage(response.data.message);
          setSuccessful(true);
        },
        (error) => {
          const resMessage =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();

          setMessage(resMessage);
          setSuccessful(false);
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card card-container">
        <img
          src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
          alt="profile-img"
          className="profile-img-card"
        />

        <Form onSubmit={handleRegister} ref={form}>
          {!successful && (
            <div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="username"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={onChangeUsername}
                  validations={[required, vusername]}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={onChangeEmail}
                  validations={[required, validEmail]}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <Input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={onChangePassword}
                  validations={[required, vpassword]}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}

          {message && (
            <div className="form-group">
              <div
                className={ successful ? "alert alert-success" : "alert alert-danger" }
                role="alert"
              >
                {message}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <CheckButton style={{ display: "none" }} ref={checkBtn} />
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

My auhService is this :

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";

const register = (username, email, password) => {
  return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
    username,
    email,
    password,
  });
};

const login = (username, password) => {
  return axios
    .post(API_URL + "signin", {
      username,
      password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }

      return response.data;
    });
};

const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
};

const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
};

export default {
  register,
  login,
  logout,
  getCurrentUser,
};
```

And this is my App.test.js :

```
import { configure, shallow, mount} from "enzyme";
import App from "./App"
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Register from "./components/Register";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });



it("renders without crashing", () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });


  describe("<Register />", () => {
    let wrapper;
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, "useState")
    useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = Enzyme.mount(Enzyme.shallow(<Register />).get(0))
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    describe("username input", () => {
        it("Should capture title correctly onChange", () => {
            const title = wrapper.find("input").at(0);
            title.instance().value = "New user";
            title.simulate("change");
            expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith("New user");
        });
    });

    describe("email input", () => {
        it("Should capture content correctly onChange", () => {
            const content = wrapper.find("new Email").at(1);
            content.instance().value = "Testing";
            content.simulate("change");
            expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith("new Email");
        });
    })
});
```

By far I was trying the first two inputs(username and email), but I'm getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined". What shall I do here? I've been trying everyhting. Thank you guys!

Comment: Where are you accessing a `child` property?

Comment: the error appears to be when I create the wrapper variable: Enzyme can't mount the component, but it's correctly imported.